# How long do Zero Value Transactions last?

Tags: transaction, tangle, permanode

Let s say we have some critical information stored as Zero Value transactions on the Tangle. How long does it last?

Which robust approaches do you recommend to keep a copy of those transactions?

I am using the testnet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nodes can choose to take a [local snapshot](https://docs.iota.works/docs/getting-started/0.1/network/nodes#local-snapshots) at any time, which would delete old transactions from their ledgers.

Therefore, to be sure that your zero value transactions are not deleted, you would need to run your own node that does not take local snapshots.

See the developer documentation for information on [running a node](https://docs.iota.org/docs/node-software/0.1/iri/how-to-guides/install-iri).

Comment: Thanks, please clarify what a local snapshot is

Comment: I have updated the question specifying that I am using the testnet

Comment: No problem. I updated the answer with a link.

Comment: Maybe storing transactions (on your db) as they are issued might be a solution. Thanks for the information provide. I ll accept your answer as the solution. Hope to get more options from the community

Comment: I have double checked the documentation, running a full nodes seems to be the best solution to the problem since it would imply full control over transactions. And would represent the most beneficial action for the Iota community